# .htaccess - create a language dir

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

For SEO friendly urls i'm using this expression:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1&titel=$2
```

The url is *domain.com/55-page-title* and it works perfect.

Now i have to determine different languages and my url should look like *domain.com/de/55-seitentitel*. I've no idea how to rewrite regular expression in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).([^/]+)$ index.php?lan=$1&id=$2&titel=$3
```

What could I insert behind '^'? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+).([^/]+)$ index.php?lan=$1&id=$2&titel=$3
```